# How to Know that which resources (Image /js/css) needs to be preload

Tags: optimization, preload

In a page how to identify or to know that which resources needs to be preload. If I get to know by inspecting through dev tools for the resources having high priority or else the resources page needs on early

Comment: Can you provide a bit more info about your scenario? Is this a simple website with static JS/CSS includes? or is it built with React/Angular/? Is this an SPA (Single Page Application) or a just a series of HTML pages (e.g. typical HTTP Request/Response)?

Comment: yes the website is made of Drupal 7 and no its not a single page application.